# subset verification using recursion c++

Tags: c++, algorithm

My task is:

> Using the `is_element_of` function, implement a function which determines whether one array is a “subset” of another (that is, whether every element in array a is also an element of array b)

```
bool is_subset(int* a, int length_a, int* b, int length_b)
bool is_element_of(int i, int* array, int length)
```

Code for `is_element_of`

```
bool is_element_of(int i, int* array, int length) {
    if (length == 0)
        return false;
    else {
        if (i == array[length - 1] || is_element_of(i, array, length - 1))
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }
}
```

Code for is_subset

```
bool is_subset(int* a, int length_a, int* b, int length_b) {
    if (length_a == 0 && length_b == 0)
        return true;
    else if (length_a != 0 && length_b == 0)
        return false;
    else {
        if (
            is_element_of(a[length_a], b, length_b) &&
            is_subset(a, length_a - 1, b, length_b)
        )
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }
}
```

Can someone please point out the problem?

Comment: btw, I strongly recommend not mixing braced control statements with inline statements - that's how Heartbleed happened.

Comment: So what is the problem? You haven't said.

Comment: The is_subset function  is not working, I don't know where to start from.

Comment: Think about how you can separate the HEAD from the TAIL of a list, then pass them into a function, then repeat the process with the TAIL( TAIL( list ) ), and so on... (using the computer-science abstract sense of head and tail).

Comment: For example, this QA: http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/6951/recursion-problem-involving-head-tail-and-xor

Comment: Thanks for advising, it is helpful

Answer (score 0):

in is_subset function, on 2nd line use this code,
if (length_a == 0 )

and

in line 8 use this code,

is_element_of(a[length_a-1], b, length_b) &&